# SSRS , I am trying to make a table where the first row agregate and remaining row

Tags: sql, reporting-services

SSRS , I am trying to make a table where the first row will be a aggregate value  and remaining rows should be displayed as such from the \DB
For Example :

```
          A    B        
          100  1
          101  2
          102  2
          103  3
          105  1
          99   1
          98   1
          96   2
          95   3
```

Basically I should create a table in SSRS , where in SSRS table should display

```
    100-105  9
     99      1
     98      1
     96      2
     95      3
```

Any experts help me achieve this , Also using Stored Proc in SQL server Database
what condition/ format should be used in SSRS 2017

Comment: added image of data and how it should get displayed

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Just use a CASE statement to define your list of values